# Background-size not working for ipad

Tags: html, css, ipad, background-image, tablet

I set the background-size color to the body and everything works fine except ipad. Ipad just ignored that property and set the oridginal background image to the top left corner.Also it ignores other background css properties, for example background position.
live example:http://www.ontoartstudio.com/
Why it doesn't work on ipad and how i can solve this problem?

Comment: Supply us with some code to play with or we can't help. Maybe also create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) .